# Is it possible to access an SQL database migrated using Django with a JavaScript ORM instead of raw SQL for a microservice architecture?

Tags: sql, django, express, web, microservices

Suppose that I have an app where the models have been created using Django ORM and Django acts like an API for authentication and gives control to the relation model User using its ORM. At the same time, we want to use Express JS to continuously update a field in one the User model for some feature that requires performance. Is it possible to use a JavaScript ORM with Express JS to update such field? If yes, then how?

Answer (score 0):

In the following tutorial [tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zTnkskp-xWs) for Golang, the database is created using SQL and a table called go_test_model is created. Then he uses the struct called GoTestModel to create a row in the table go_test_model.

This basically means that if we create an app called api in Django and add in it a model called Example, then to handle that model in Golang we just create a struct called ApiExample and from there we can have CRUD access to the same table, there might be some conflicts in the fields datatypes between GORM and Django ORM but integrity is still applied in the database itself.

So this particular example solves my problem with Golang and can be replicated using Node JS.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Sequelize](https://sequelize.org/) for using native functions for performing queries instead of writing raw queries.

Also, please refer to [Models](https://sequelize.org/docs/v6/core-concepts/model-basics/) section to define models.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).